# Conditionally assign multiple keys to Object

Tags: javascript

I have multiple properties that can be assigned to an Object depending on the **same conditional**

```
const condition = some boolean;
const foo = [

                bar.fizz,
                bar.fuzz,
                bar.fat,
                condition ? bar.arr[index].bat : '',
                condition ? bar.arr[index].bot : '',               
           ];
```

Is there any way I can conditionally assign those last two in the ternary (because they rely on the same conditional)?

I know of

```
 ...(conditional ? [
               bar.arr[index].bat,
               bar.arr[index].bot
     ] 
            : []),
```

But the only problem with that is that if the conditional is false...then those indices won't exist in the final object. I'll need them to default to empty strings.

I think

```
...(conditional ? [
                   bar.arr[index].bat,
                   bar.arr[index].bot
         ] 
                : ['', '']),
```

would work? Anyone see anything wrong with that or is there a better way?

Comment: There first option looks the most readable to me. Repeating the same condition isn't a problem imo.

Comment: mm..any thoughts on efficiency though. Or would it be trivial, especially for only a few properties like in the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, the first one is very readable to me. If you are just going to do it for two indices.

In the case that you are dealing with more than two. The third one is great

```
...(conditional ? [
               bar.arr[index].bat,
               bar.arr[index].bot
     ] 
            : ['', '']),
```

even better if you just create an array of the same size as your intention, and fill it with empty string such as

```
...(conditional ? [
               bar.arr[index].bat,
               bar.arr[index].bot
     ] 
            : Array(PUT SIZE OF ARRAY YOU WANT HERE).fill("")),
```

Comment: Just gonna use separate ternaries, but I'm accepting your solution bc of the Array(size) creativity

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is a little bit clumsy, but give a try:

```
condition : bar.arr[index].bot ? bar.arr[index].bot 
    : bar.arr[index].bat ? bar.arr[index].bat 
        : ''
```